# npm not installed in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, npm

```
pp@pp-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually install NodeJS and NPM in Ubuntu and I follow this tutorial (**How To Install Using a PPA**):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

I have tried it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS without problems.

**Warning**: *Try to install in a clean Ubuntu.*

Hope It works for you!